Can't connect to Neo4j Desktop database using latest Neo4j version, new database, and django_neomodel (Authentication Error)
So it throws the exception:
 neo4j.exceptions.AuthError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Security.Unauthorized} {message: The client is unauthorized due to authentication failure.}
But I went up a few levels in the exception and here:

auth is set to "None" essentially.
My global variables are as such:

I'm guessing this is something wrong with my django_neomodel setup, but I have django_neomodel installed and added to my Django project's INSTALLED_APPS.
Reason username/password is not neo4j is because neo4j:neo4j does not work (it's not possible to set password neo4j in the latest desktop app), neither does neo4j:ArrowGlue (the password I thought I set when creating the new database).
So in the database tab of Neo4j Browser I played ":server user add" and added ArrowGlue:ArrowGlue as an admin level Role.

Now I figured it was because I had my URL variable as a straight environment variable.  So changing to sit inside of settings.py and I'm at the next step of this connection trouble:
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\neo4j\_sync\io\_bolt.py", line 808, in fetch_message
  res = self._process_message(tag, fields)
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\neo4j\_sync\io\_bolt5.py", line 361, in _process_message
  response.on_failure(summary_metadata or {})
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\neo4j\_sync\io\_common.py", line 247, in on_failure
  raise Neo4jError.hydrate(**metadata)

neo4j.exceptions.ClientError: {code: Neo.ClientError.Security.CredentialsExpired} {message: ACCESS on database 'neo4j' is not allowed.
The credentials you provided were valid, but must be changed before you can use this instance. If this is the first time you are using Neo4j, this is to ensure you are not using the default credentials in production. If you are not using default credentials, you are getting this message because an administrator requires a password change.
To change your password, issue an `ALTER CURRENT USER SET PASSWORD FROM 'current password' TO 'new password'` statement against the system database.}


I solved it.  First the NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL must be in settings.py (defined there; so load it securely from environment).
NEOMODEL_NEO4J_BOLT_URL = 'bolt://neo4j:ArrowGlue@localhost:7687'

worked for me where ArrowGlue password I had set prior at some stage.  The user I created still doesn't work.  But this is fine enough to move past.
I know it connected this time because it went through Node creation code without Authentication Error and new model label "Node" shows up as a colored tag in Neo4j Browser.
